# SQL for Selecting Data with Codition

Tags: sql, oracle

in need a fast SQL for selcting my Data.
I have a Table `a` which look like the following:
[image]

And another Table `b` which look like the following:

[image]

In `a`u can specify which data from `b` i need. Its the Flag `a.kba_inkl` (`I` = Inclusiv, `E` = Excluisiv)
The Key From both Tables are the first four Columns.

The First Row from `a` means all Artikel from `b` which has `b.art_be = a.kba_be`.

The Second Row from `a` means without Artickles from `b` where `b.art_be = a.kba_be and b.art_wg = a.kba_wg`. And so on.

In `a`: `0` means ALL (From `1-99`)

In `b` can't appear `a` `0`

Table a:

```
|------|------|------|-------|--------|
|kba_be|kba_wg|kba_ag|kba_anr|kba_inkl|
|------|------|------|-------|--------|
|10    |0     |0     |0      |I       |
|------|------|------|-------|--------|
|10    |10    |0     |0      |E       |
|------|------|------|-------|--------|
|10    |20    |30    |0      |E       |
|------|------|------|-------|--------|
|20    |10    |0     |0      |I       |
|------|------|------|-------|--------|
|20    |0     |0     |0      |E       |
|------|------|------|-------|--------|
```

Table b:

```
|------|------|------|-------|
|art_be|art_wg|art_ag|art_anr|
|------|------|------|-------|
|10    |20    |30    |40     |
|------|------|------|-------|
|10    |10    |1     |5      |
|------|------|------|-------|
|10    |5     |30    |20     |
|------|------|------|-------|
|10    |10    |80    |50     |
|------|------|------|-------|
|10    |60    |30    |60     |
|------|------|------|-------|
|20    |10    |50    |50     |
|------|------|------|-------|
|20    |60    |30    |60     |
|------|------|------|-------|
```

Result:

```
|------|------|------|-------|
|art_be|art_wg|art_ag|art_anr|
|------|------|------|-------|
|10    |5     |30    |20     |
|------|------|------|-------|
|10    |60    |30    |60     |
|------|------|------|-------|
|20    |10    |50    |50     |
|------|------|------|-------|
```

Does anybody has an Idea?

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT: Maybe the Table a should be grouped like this:

```
|------|------|------|-------|--------|
|kba_be|kba_wg|kba_ag|kba_anr|kba_inkl|
|------|------|------|-------|--------|
|10    |0     |0     |0      |I       |
|------|------|------|-------|--------|
|20    |0     |0     |0      |E       |
|------|------|------|-------|--------|
|10    |10    |0     |0      |E       |
|------|------|------|-------|--------|
|20    |10    |0     |0      |I       |
|------|------|------|-------|--------|
|10    |20    |30    |0      |E       |
|------|------|------|-------|--------|
```

And then loop through the rows.

Comment: These cryptic column names make it more complicated to understand the question. Please provide the exact mapping between columns of both tables.

Comment: I Edit it a bit.

Comment: Please, provide sample data and expected output in text format. Images are welcome, but they're useless for data processing.

Comment: Actually it is not clear what is your inclusion / exclusion logic and priorities of rule enforcement. I would advise to clarify these  - and then provide valid examples covering all  possible cases.

Comment: In my Opion its clear when we look at the sorted Table a. That the order to be processed.

Comment: Let me place it this way - is an `a` table with only exclude row a valid table ? What set are you excluding from ? you have a rule 'exclude all _be=20' as a first rule according to your logic and order - what is the initial set ? I think I am going to give up ... You may say that it is clear to you - but somehow I doubt that you have investigated in depth  what is it that you are looking for ....

Comment: A Table a with only excluded values is valid. When that Table is set, no row should be returned. The inital set is, when some Data with I are in Table a otherwise the return is null. I dont know what more i should say :/

Answer (score 0):

So there are 2 parts of the query *inclusive* and *exclusive*.

The exclusive can be implemented using `minus` operator.

```
with a as 
(
select 10 kba_be,0 kba_wg,0 kba_ag,0 kba_anr,'I' kba_incl from dual  union all
select 10 kba_be,10 kba_wg,0 kba_ag,0 kba_anr,'E' kba_incl from dual  union all
select 10 kba_be,20 kba_wg,30 kba_ag,0 kba_anr,'E' kba_incl from dual  
),
b as 
(
select 10 art_be,20 art_wg,30 art_ag,0 art_anr from dual  union all
select 10 art_be,10 art_wg,1 art_ag,5 art_anr  from dual  union all
select 10 art_be,5 art_wg,30 art_ag,20 art_anr from dual  union all
select 10 art_be,10 art_wg,80 art_ag,50 art_anr from dual  union all
select 10 art_be,60 art_wg,30 art_ag,60 art_anr  from dual
)
select b.* from 
a,b 
where 
       a.kba_incl = 'I'
and    b.art_be = a.kba_be 
and   (b.art_wg = a.kba_wg or a.kba_wg=0)
and   (b.art_ag = a.kba_ag or a.kba_ag=0)
minus 
select b.* from 
a,b 
where 
       a.kba_incl = 'E'
and    b.art_be = a.kba_be 
and   (b.art_wg = a.kba_wg or a.kba_wg=0)
and   (b.art_ag = a.kba_ag or a.kba_ag=0)
```

result

```
10  5   30  20
10  60  30  60
```

Comment: Your SQL is Good, but with the expanded Tables it wont work correct.

Comment: @AntonSchrage according to your exclude rule: rows with `art_be=20` should be  excluded - so how come your expected results contain one?

Comment: because my rule said that `art_be=20` and `art_wg=10` should be included

Comment: @AntonSchrage That is not what your `a` table  says , it says  `20    |0     |0     |0      |E`

Comment: Your're right, but if i say in table a `|20    |10    |0     |0      |I       |` then i wanted to see those records.

Comment: @AntonSchrage don't those 2 rules strike you as contradictory? Who is to tell which one has the priority? Just to try to understand your logic -  If you had no include rule at all - doesn't it mean that the result is `null`? Then if I exclude something doesn't it mean that I am excluding from those that have been included?

Comment: In the Top I added Table a which is sorted like `order by kba_anr, kba_agr, kba_wg, kba_be`. This should be the order to be processed.